# How to write a dynamic time dropdown in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, benchmarking

I want to display timings in dropdown but there so much of data to mention in every controller. If i use any directive for this then it fixes my problem.

code:

```
$scope.timings = ['7:00 am', '7:15 am', '7:30 am', '7:45 am','8:00 am', '8:15 am', 
                  '8:30 am','8:45 am','9:00 am', '9:15 am', '9:30 am', '9:45 am',
                  '10:00 am', '10:15 am','10:30 am', '10:45 am', '11:00 am', '11:15 am', '11:30 am', '11:45 am',
                  '12:00 pm', '12:15 pm', '12:30 pm', '12:45 pm', '1:00 pm','1:15 pm',
                  '1:30 pm', '1:45 pm', '2:00 pm', '2:15 pm', '2:30 pm', '2:45 pm',
                  '3:00 pm', '3:15 pm', '3:30 pm', '3:45 pm', '4:00 pm', '4:15 pm', 
                  '4:30 pm', '4:45 pm','5:00 pm', '5:15 pm', '5:30 pm', '5:45 pm',
                  '6:00 pm', '6:15 pm', '6:30 pm', '6:45 pm','7:00 pm', '7:15 pm', 
                  '7:30 pm', '7:45 pm','8:00 pm', '8:15 pm', '8:30 pm', '8:45 pm',
                  '9:00 pm', '9:15 pm', '9:30 pm', '9:45 pm','10:00 pm', '10:15 pm', 
                  '10:30 pm', '10:45 pm', '11:00 pm', '11:15 pm', '11:30 pm', '11:45pm',
                  '12:00 am', '12:15 am', '12:30 am', '12:45 am', '1:00 am','1:15 am',
                  '1:30 am', '1:45 am', '2:00 am', '2:15 am', '2:30 am', '2:45 am',
                  '3:00 am', '3:15 am', '3:30 am', '3:45 am', '4:00 am', '4:15 am', 
                  '4:30 am', '4:45 am','5:00 am', '5:15 am', '5:30 am', '5:45 am',
                  '6:00 am', '6:15 am', '6:30 am', '6:45 am'
                  ];
```

Now i am using like this. Could anyone suggest me a better solution?
   Thanks in advance

Comment: I have no idea what your problem is. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: It is unclear what you have currently and what you want to achieve, Share more code and elaborate your question please.

Comment: @apairet - i am saying that i want to get the timings using any loop code it should be automatic not like how i am writing now. I can't repeat the same array writing on every controller.

Comment: What about existing code, like http://www.dnasir.com/github/angular-timepicker/demo.html , https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for this.

```
app.directive('timePicker', function() {
return {
restrict: 'E',
require: 'ngModel',
replace: true,
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
  scope.timings = ['7:00 am', '7:15 am', '7:30 am', '7:45 am', '8:00 am', '8:15 am',
    '8:30 am', '8:45 am', '9:00 am', '9:15 am', '9:30 am', '9:45 am',
    '10:00 am', '10:15 am', '10:30 am', '10:45 am', '11:00 am', '11:15 am', '11:30 am',   '11:45 am',
    '12:00 pm', '12:15 pm', '12:30 pm', '12:45 pm', '1:00 pm', '1:15 pm',
    '1:30 pm', '1:45 pm', '2:00 pm', '2:15 pm', '2:30 pm', '2:45 pm',
    '3:00 pm', '3:15 pm', '3:30 pm', '3:45 pm', '4:00 pm', '4:15 pm',
    '4:30 pm', '4:45 pm', '5:00 pm', '5:15 pm', '5:30 pm', '5:45 pm',
    '6:00 pm', '6:15 pm', '6:30 pm', '6:45 pm', '7:00 pm', '7:15 pm',
    '7:30 pm', '7:45 pm', '8:00 pm', '8:15 pm', '8:30 pm', '8:45 pm',
    '9:00 pm', '9:15 pm', '9:30 pm', '9:45 pm', '10:00 pm', '10:15 pm',
    '10:30 pm', '10:45 pm', '11:00 pm', '11:15 pm', '11:30 pm', '11:45pm',
    '12:00 am', '12:15 am', '12:30 am', '12:45 am', '1:00 am', '1:15 am',
    '1:30 am', '1:45 am', '2:00 am', '2:15 am', '2:30 am', '2:45 am',
    '3:00 am', '3:15 am', '3:30 am', '3:45 am', '4:00 am', '4:15 am',
    '4:30 am', '4:45 am', '5:00 am', '5:15 am', '5:30 am', '5:45 am',
    '6:00 am', '6:15 am', '6:30 am', '6:45 am'
  ];

},
template: '<select name="timepicker" id="timePicker">\
<option value="{{time}}" ng-repeat="time in timings">{{time}}</option>\
</select>'
};
});
```

[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/cIhFDtAgh6aFBstgqxqm?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks. I want to use like this only